# Jquery Ajax Datatable reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using jquery datatable to list my database values.
      I want create a country and its state in same page while that initially the state datatable is empty.Once I create country the country id is generated and can create state with that country id in same page.It also created fine but the problem is datatable is not reloading it should show the state which was created but its not showing.The problem is country id which is generated is not passing to the ajax parameter in datatable while reloading it.

```
 country_id=$("#country_id").val();
    dataTable = $('#example').DataTable( {
         "serverSide": true,
    // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
        "ajax": {
        "url": datatable_url,
        "type": "POST",
        data:{country_id: $("#country_id").val()},
        error: function () {  // error handling
            $(".table-grid-error").html("");
            $("#table").append('<tbody class="employee-grid-error"><tr><th colspan="3">No data found in the server</th></tr></tbody>');
            $("#table-grid_processing").css("display", "none");
        }
    },

    ],
});
```

I reloading it by

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'url',
    type: "POST",
    data: {
     //data
    },
    success: function (data) {
              reload_tabless();
   },

function reload_tabless() {
dataTable.ajax.reload(null, false); //reload datatable ajax
}
```

Please help me rectify it.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you have the `url` hard coded to the string `'url'` in the code that should do the ajax call before calling `reload_tabless()` which most probably makes the ajax call to fail, thus not executing the success callback.

I don't think you need that extra ajax call. Simply execute `reload_tabless` instead of that ajax call.

Comment: Actually through that URL i am inserting the state against the country id which is inserted in header in same page ,once the state inserted the datatable should reload and show that newly created state

Answer (score 0):

Use "destroy": true inside DataTable section and call DataTable function again.

It will reload DataTable without postback.